# Преобразовать массив в нужную структуру Объектов

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Ребят, помогите решить одну задачку, не ладиться у меня с массивами.
Суть такая, у меня на входе есть массив массивов.

```
items: [
        [ 'группа', 'цена', 'описание', 'порция', 'блюдо' ],
        [ 'кофе', '100', 'кофе с молоком', '300', 'капучино' ],
        [ '', '200', 'Кофе с молоком', '300', 'Латте' ],
        [ 'Колла', '60', 'оригинальная', '500', 'колла' ],
        [ '', '100', 'zero', '500', 'колла' ],
        [ 'Вино', '600', 'белое вино', '250', 'Шато Бло бло' ],
        [ '', '500', 'красное вино', '250', 'Шато Тро ло ло' ],
      ]
```

Изначально, я пытался решить проблему отсутствия данных в массиве в колонке группа (такое может быть)
[image: Пример массива]
Решил я это следующим способом.
создал вот такое computed свойство:

```
createMenu () {
      let value = ''

      return this.items.slice(1).map((item) => {
        let newItem = item[0]
        if (newItem) {
          value = newItem
        } else {
          newItem = value
        }
        return newItem
      })
    }
```

Все прекрасно, но нужно как-то из этого массива сделать нужную структуру, Объектов.
А я ни как не могу к этому подступиться.
Структура должна выглядеть примерно так:

[image: Пример структуры]

ну и присутствовать соответствующая логика.
Если я бегу циклом по группе, и если значение новое, я создаю новый item, в него закидываю блюда и тд.
А если оно такое же, то я не создаю новый item а просто закидываю туда блюда.
Я что-то пока не могу понять, с чего начать(

Буду благодарен любой наводке))

Comment: я так понял если группа пустая, то берется предыдущая?

Comment: Да все верно)))

Comment: https://codepen.io/Manfrid/pen/YzWNJYG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то должно быть что-то примерно такое:

```js
// заполняем пустые груп неймы и возвращаем обновленные массивы
const fillEmptyGroupNames = (items) => {
  let previousGroupName = 'Кофе';

  return items.map((item) => {
    const [groupName, ...otherFields] = item;

    if (groupName) {
      previousGroupName = groupName;
      return item;
    }

    return [previousGroupName, ...otherFields];
  });
};

// конвертируем в нужную вам структуру
const convertToStructuredMenu = (items) => {
  // конфиг, в котором ключ - название группы,
  // значение - индекс в результирующем массиве
  const alreadyUsedGroups = {};

  return items.reduce((
    acc,
    [
      groupName,
      name,
      description,
      price,
      measure,
    ],
  ) => {
    const item = {
      name,
      description,
      prices: {
        price,
        measure,
      },
    };

    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(alreadyUsedGroups, groupName)) {
      acc.push({ name: groupName, items: [item] });
      alreadyUsedGroups[groupName] = acc.length - 1;

      return acc;
    }

    acc[alreadyUsedGroups[groupName]].items.push(item);

    return acc;
  }, [])
};

export default {
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      [ 'группа', 'цена', 'описание', 'порция', 'блюдо' ],
      [ 'Кофе', '100', 'кофе с молоком', '300', 'капучино' ],
      [ '', '200', 'Кофе с молоком', '300', 'Латте' ],
      [ 'Колла', '60', 'оригинальная', '500', 'колла' ],
      [ '', '100', 'zero', '500', 'колла' ],
      [ 'Вино', '600', 'белое вино', '250', 'Шато Бло бло' ],
      [ '', '500', 'красное вино', '250', 'Шато Тро ло ло' ],
    ],
  }),
  computed: {
    menu() {
      const [, ...items] = this.items; // извлекаем всё, кроме хедеров
      return fillEmptyGroupNames(items);
    },
    structuredMenu() {
      return convertToStructuredMenu(this.menu);
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Максим, добрый день.
Спасибо вам огромное за это решение, я увы такое придумать бы не смог, только прочитать ваше.
Только там какой-то странный результат получается, все элементы только по первой буквой или цифрой))

Comment: Что-то не могу найти где собака порылась))

Comment: Опечатался в строке `const [, items] = this.items;`, тут надо `[, ...items]` спрэд оператор. Поправил пример кода в ответе.

Comment: Максим, спасибо большое.
Буду разбираться как это у вас получилось)))
Ну что-то сложновато переварить мне(((

Спасибо еще раз!!!
А то я только и что смог - это сделать проверку на похожее значение))))

Comment: Там на самом деле всё просто:

`fillEmptyGroupNames` - тут мы мапим значения, если значение с индексом 0 валидное, то возвращаем его и кладем его значение в переменную `previousGroupName`, иначе спрэдим все остальные значения, а как групп нейи берем значение из `previousGroupName`. Вот эта строка `const [groupName, ...otherFields] = item` - это просто [деструктуризация](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring).

`convertToStructuredMenu ` - тут мы просто создаем массив объектов при помощи `reduce`, извлечение значений тоже через деструктуризацию.

Comment: Ну а реализация вынесена в отдельные функции для удобочитаемости и потому что в [vue style guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/) рекомендуется делать вычисляемые свойства коротким без реализации сложной логики непосредственно в них. Единственное я бы для проверки групп неймов делал еще приведение к нижнему регистру, чтобы кофе и Кофе не обрабатывались, как разные значения.

Comment: Максим, еще раз спасибо за пояснение.
Это действительно очень ценно, с спрэт операторами знаком, но всегда как-то обходило стороной их использование.
Но про Деструктуризацию нужно обязательно прочитать!)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115493/discussion-between-alexander-and--).

Comment: Максим, простите пожалуйста за беспокойство, а что если в моем примере, пунктов (цена, порция) - может быть больше чем по одному разу.
Что тогда сделать в результирующей функции, нужно заводить объект.
Я вот только этот момент не смог переварить.

Comment: Ой, получилось)))
prices: {
        prices: {
          price,
          price2
        },
        measures: {
          measure,
          masure2
        }
      },

Comment: Вы может либо складывать цены, либо сделать например массив цен, ну или как вы указали выше, price1 и т.д., тут как удобнее организовывайте структуру.